# Create a Shared Inventory with different amounts for each user (PHP,MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I usually have code to share but I am truly trying to get advice on where to even get started with this.  I will do my best to explain but Googling is just not helping me and I have no clue where to start.

**What I am trying to accomplish:**
Basically i want to be able to create a table(or several tables) that contain items that can be marked as owned as I get them.  While that seems easy enough I run into my issue when trying to allow more than 1 person use the inventory items but have their own inventories of what they already have.

**What I have already done:**
Created a a database with 2 tables.  One table holds the user information for each person that will be using the inventory and be able to mark what they each own.  The other table is a huge list of inventory items that each user will ultimately be able to mark as owned.

I know this is not much to go on but I truly am just asking if anyone knows of anything to help me get started.  I am not looking for an already functioning inventory management system and this will be in an internal closed network ultimately with a couple hundred people using it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: User_id,item_id (and quantity - if appropriate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need three total tables to solve this problem. From my understanding of what you want to accomplish here is, You have a bunch of people and more than a bunch of products that people will select if they own. For example, I am a Pencil dealer and there are 3 products called Pencils, Erasers and Sharpeners in the Products. As I am a pencil dealer, I will select Pencil.

At the same time, you also want other Pencil dealers to select a pencil from the list of products. If you really want to accomplish this, then here is how your database design should be.

[image]

The fields that vary from user to user can be created within `stocks` table and the fields that are static from item to an item can be stored within `items` table.

This way, users can share inventory by selecting the products they have and also can have their own inventories. If you want the complete private product for a specific user's inventory, You can add a field called `is_private` in `products` table and just avoid showing that item to other users to select.

I think that's what you are trying to accomplish here. Let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  Are you saying that for each user/item owned there will be a line item in the stock table?  Example being if 100 people each have 147 items there would be 14,700 lines in the stock table?

Comment: @BrandonOrndorff, Yes. And if you are thinking it's a huge number that will slow down your queries, It won't. You can have 1000 people having 1470 items each and still, your queries won't slow down even on a server having 1GB RAM.

Comment: Great thank you, seems it will be easier than I thought.  I will give this setup a go and see how it goes.

Comment: Sure! @BrandonOrndorff